# Workflow Error in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, custom-list

I created a new workflow. When users add new item to the, the workflow send an email to users. I checked workflow and i got the error as follow image.

[image]

My email's content as follow:

[image]

Why got I this error?

Comment: Please check the recipients of the email are SharePoint site users.

Comment: The recipients of the mail true. @AvijitSur

Answer (score 0):

Looking out the picture, it's all right, I suspect that is the email.

Following is an example of what the action might look like in a workflow step,

```
Email Variable: approvers
```

or

```
Email "user account"
```

where "user account" must contain the same display name of the site.

Note: if you use other e-mail such as @outlook, @gmail and other, not will work and will get this error. Send mail only work with user of SharePoint existent.

example(one scenarie for reflect):

> my name is John Smith, in SharePoint my display name is "Smith, John", then the command should look like this: `Email Smith, John`

Search link: [Support OFFICE](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Workflow-actions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6)

Maybe this help you.

Comment: Thanks for advice @b1c10. But my problem's reason "tıklayınız" link. I edited the link and problem solved. User's mail isn't incorrect.

Comment: I tried to help you, but I'm glad you managed to solve. @zengel